# Android Mysql database using php json volley error

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-volley

I just creating an Android app for Mysql CRUD operations using php,json & volley.. It works fine on Custom ListView and showing all the inserted details.. but the problem is i cannot set the ListView clicked item to EditText with required id.. please help..

```
public class EditDelte extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText ename,ephon,eclas;
    private Button btnupdate,btndelt;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editdelt_activity);
        ename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        ephon=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        eclas=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        btnupdate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btndelt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        singleItems();
    }

    private void singleItems() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.SINGL_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    final String id=getIntent().getStringExtra("ids");
                    Model model=new Model(Integer.parseInt(id),jsonObject.getString("name"),jsonObject.getString("phone_number"),jsonObject.getString("classes"));
                    //Model model=new Model(Integer.parseInt(id),jsonObject.getString("name"),jsonObject.getString("phone"),jsonObject.getString("classes"));
                    ename.setText(model.getName());
                    ephon.setText(model.getPhone_number());//here is the problem i got i cannot set the values to edittext//
                    eclas.setText(model.getClasses());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
}`
```

Comment: please share you error occurring in log-cat and also if you have multiple json response please share

Comment: `eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824`                log-cat showing only these errors, no app crashing..